# If a function returns a certain type, what are my options for returning errors?

Tags: c++

In my particular instance, I have a function to calculate a checksum, which returns a uint8_t. What would be options for showing the checksum verification has been unsuccessful? Normally I'd return -1 but obviously not an option. Return an int and cast it?

Comment: Are errors usual? If not, have you considered exceptions?

Comment: Under what circumstances causes the checksum calculation to fail to calculate a checksum?

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error{"checksum error"};`, `assert`, `std::optional`, `std::terminate` and `std::cout << "checksum error"; for (;;);` are all valid error reporting mechanisms. Which one you use depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: `Normally I'd return -1` In C++? One word: exceptions.

Comment: Have you considered returning the status and modifying a parameter or vice versa (returning the error status by modifying a parameter)?

Comment: I don't understand.  A function that calculates a checksum should return a checksum.  A function that verifies a checksum should return a bool.  Are you somehow conflating the two operations?  Maybe you should share with us the signature of the function(s) you are writing.

Comment: @nwp, that should probably be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That’s easily the worst solution in almost all scenarios, widespread though it may be. 

Comment: Thanks all. I'd initially been verifying the checksum when calculating it before returning it - suspect the better way is to just separate them out

Comment: @Eljay If the input to the checksum is correct, then when the calculated checksum is included in another checksum calculation, it should equal zero

Comment: Two routines:  `uint8_t CalculateChecksum()` and `bool VerifyChecksum(uint8_t checksum)`.

Comment: @eljay both of those would be identical functions though - would checking that the second call equals 0 suffice?

Comment: @HarryAdams • They should not be identical functions.  They do different things.

Comment: @Eljay the checksum sums a set of bytes, modulo 256, and gets the twos complement. The input bytes are set so that if you do this and include the checksum, it will produce a checksum of 0. So seems like it can be done with the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 options:

1. Adding an error state argument that passes by reference and check its state afterwords:

   ```
   int state = 0;
   auto checksum = checksum(data, state);
   if(state) //handle error
   ```
2. You can track state in an object that manages the checksum:

   ```
   CSummer summer;
   auto checksum = summer.sum(data);
   if(summer.state) //handle error
   ```
3. You can throw exceptions from summer:

   ```
   uint8_t sum;
   try
   {
      sum = summer(data);
   }
   catch(const std::exception &ex)
   {
     //handle error
   }
   ```
4. Separate the two functions: have a function to get the checksum and another to verify.

Comment: Same comment as for Garrett. The first solution is almost always bad. The second solution as well, except it’s more convoluted. The third solution can be OK, depending on the situation.

Comment: Disagree with Konrad. #1 and #2 are what I'd expect to see. #3 can be OK but is probably way overkill.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I’m surprised. What am I missing? In fact, in reference to your comment elsewhere I’d call option 2 laughably absurd (made more so by the anachronistic MFC naming convention). 1 is not absurd, just bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph seen the same response a few times across here - what's so bad about 1?

Comment: @HarryAdams Fundamentally it’s an API that’s easy to use wrongly (not checking the error value), it contains redundant initialisation, it prevents use of `const`, it’s verbose, and it uses parameters for output rather than input (I strongly advocate exclusively using return values for output — this vastly simplifies API design). It also simply offers no material advantage over using e.g. `std::optional`, outside of extremely low-level code where you might want to reuse the same flag. Needless to say this should never be done in high-level APIs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ah okay, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I am not quite sure if you want to calculate a checksum or want to verify whether a checksum is correct. If you want both, you can-

1. Use two functions: one for calculating the checksum(returns uint8_t) and the other for verifying if it's correct(returns a Boolean). This is the best way in my opinion.
2. Return a structure (struct) from your function. The structure will contain a uint8_t(the checksum) and another element telling if the checksum is correct.
3. Throw an exception.
4. Modify a global flag.

Comment: “Modify a global flag” — really?!

Comment: Just one of many options - doesn't mean it is particularly good. It's pretty lame, actually, and I know it. :v

Comment: Right, so why mention it? The point of Stack Overflow is to provide *good* answers, not to give an exhaustive list of good *and bad* options. It makes sense to list options since there are different best answers depending on the scenario. but (outside of emulating a CPU) I can’t see a situation where (4) would be an acceptable option. I know it’s used in POSIX but that’s a *bad* example, and poor API design.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a poor design. But using a global variable is the best I could think of in case the function prototype can not be changed and still keeping things as simple as possible. It would be better if the questioner stated the circumstances a bit more clearly.

Comment: _"not to give an exhaustive list of good and bad options"_ Actually, naming bad options is extremely valuable, as long as you call them out as bad (and explain why). Not mentioning them at all has no value at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, by all means mention them to explain why they’re bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably decide if you want your return value to indicate failure/success OR the checksum. If you function signature is currently `uint8_t calc_checksum(Foo& bar)` you could perhaps try changing it to something like `bool calc_checksum(Foo& bar, uint8_t& checksum)` or `bool calc_checksum(Foo& bar, uint8_t* checksum_ptr)` where that last parameter is filled with your result and the return result is true if an error occurred. The former allows you to do something like

```
uint8_t checksum;
if(calc_checksum(bar, checksum)) {
    // handle the error in calc_checksum
}
```

Otherwise you can simply throw an exception. One of the differences is that the method above will silently fail if the return value is not checked, so in that sense exceptions are preferable.

Comment: Please no. This is a terrible solution in C++ (and most other modern languages). There are *very few* situations, almost exclusively in low level systems programming, where this is acceptable. See nwp’s comment for a non-exhaustive list of better solutions.

Comment: Meh, it's fine. In reality you are going to be interfacing with plenty of C-like functions that work this way. What's one more? All but one of nwp's solutions is bad, and all but two are laughably absurd (perhaps deliberately so). The remaining contender, `std::optional`, is fine but nowhere near as familiar and clear as simply returning `true` on success.

Comment: When I run into the kind of design decision OP based this question on I usually use the solution I specified in this answer exactly because many of the functions I interface with are implemented this way. I would probably say throwing an exception (from within the function itself) is a superior solution; it just takes slightly more work to decide which exception you going to throw and then making sure that every time you call the function it is within a try somewhere that catches that exception. Someone, COULD just ignore the return result, but I find in practice that I at least never do.